# Width and height of parent element not equal to image dimensions

Tags: html, css, height, width, gallery

A friend ask me to take a look on one issue on his site. In the portfolio section on the website, there is a border around the `div` and a rollover evect when the images are hovered. However, there is one weird issue, the height of the box containing the image and all data is larger by 5px in height.

The image is square, and all of the parent elements have `width` and `height` elements set to `100%`, there are no paddings or margins that could have caused this, so I can't seem to find a reason for this.

Could anyone point to a location where is this happening and how to fix it?

A sample code describing this problem can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6juSZ/2/).

Thanks!

Comment: "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed. To avoid it, you should create a minimal but complete example that shows the problem and paste the code in the question. See also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Sorry, I understand the description is quite vague, but as I wasnt involved initially in this website the code is hard to read and creating a isolated example seemed like it wont portray all of the needed elements.

Comment: I have updated the code to include a link to a sandbox version of this with both the problem and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is heavily awful, but putting display: block on the images will fix it.

The reason is that images are inline elements, so you will get some phantom padding to the bottom to account for things like the bottom of g, p, q, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this was the cause. I am sorry for the illegible code, I had the same remarks as well :)